# Registering a .ru domain in USA

Tags: domains, registration

I am located in the USA and am interested in registering a .ru domain.  I am having some trouble finding a good domain registration site -- light research on 101domain turns up more than a handful of poor/scammy reviews and I haven't found a single review for http://nic.ru though I like the looks of it (at least, more than 101domain).

If anyone knows of a good domain registration site for .ru domains or has any insight into finding such a site, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Bunny

Comment: Update:
I decided to go ahead and register "meryn.ru" with http://nic.ru.  First off, it is very helpful to me as a non-Russian speaker to have the option to view the website in English instead of relying on Google translate.  
Compared to a regular domain buying experience, it is a bit more involved.  Proof of identification (specifically, passport) is required.  However, it went much more smoothly than expected.  I was happy to see that the Name Servers resolved in just a few hours.  Nic.ru --> Thumbs up

Answer (score 4):

not sure if this helps, but here seems to be a list of accredited registrars: http://www.cctld.ru/en/registrators/